# Python: pool.apply_async() only runs one thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to use python code in the following style.  It worked when I tested with simple functions.  However, when I apply the same method to more complicated functions, it only runs one thread.  I.e., I only saw the first function (localFunctions.f1) got executed.  What am I missing?
--  A python newbie

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import localFunctions

result_list = []

def get_result(result):
    result_list.append(result)

def apply_async_with_callback():
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
    pool.apply_async(localFunctions.f1, args=(val1, val2, ), callback=get_result)
    pool.apply_async(localFunctions.f2, args=(val3, val4, val5, ), callback=get_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

apply_async_with_callback()
```

Comment: Don't you need an `if __name__ == '__main__'` in there somewhere?

Comment: what is your `localFunction.f1` and `localFunction.f2`?

Comment: @figs: Yes, I used if __name__ == '__main__'.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    apply_async_with_callback()

Comment: @ozgur:
Those are the functions that I wrote to do various things, like, SSH into some servers and ran some commands, etc.

Comment: @snake.new You are saying that it works for simple functions but not for complicated functions. We need to know what exactly you are doing in a "complicated" function.

Comment: @ozgur:
Without posting the entire code, here is the rough idea of those localFunctions.  For one function, I'd SSH to a server, run a bunch of commands. For another function, I'd go through a number of lists of things, loop through those lists, login to a number of servers, then run a bunch of commands on one server at a time.  Both functions contain other function calls.

Comment: I initially used the following code: 

result1 = pool.apply_async(localFunctions.f1, args=()) 
result2 = pool.apply_async(localFUnctions.f2, args=()) 
val1, val2 = result1.get() 
val3, val4 = result2.get()

This initiated both threads.  However, it failed to handle sys.exit inside of localFunctions.  Without better idea, I changed it to current code to handle sys.exit().  But I don't get the second thread to run, somehow.